# Asigning postback trigger to control inside ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, c#-4.0, updatepanel

I have a ListView inside UpdatePanel. Each row of ListView contains some buttons. One button invokes method which sends file (Response.WriteFile(...)) so it should be treated as post back trigger and my question is how can I achieve this? When I put ID of this button into triggers section of UpdatePanel I get error "(...) control was not found(...)". 
Data is binded into ListView only during first page load

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the entire controls as a triggers.  See example below.  You can also do it in the code.

```
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger;
trigger=new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = Button2.ID;
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(trigger);

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label">Static Text:</asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton01</asp:LinkButton><br>
<hr />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Text in UpdPanel</asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `PostBackTrigger` for the listview containing the buttons.

Comment: can you explain more about why that well help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you are encouraged to describe solutions, instead of simply post them, to guide, and not dictate.